# Azure CI/CD Pipeline. Running .net core build and test in release pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I've configured build pipeline and upon successful CI completion, it triggers release artifact i.e release pipeline. Now in release pipeline, I want to run integration test. The solution build it self failing.

Git repository: [Git repo link](https://github.com/vivekkranjan/AzurePipeline)

Build CI Pipeline:

[image]

Release CD Pipeline:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like it. But with the information you've provided, we can't help you to fix this.

Comment: @jessehouwing What information you need. Added more screenshots. My intention is to execute integration test once the build CI triggers release CD.

Comment: Looks like you should add a `dotnet test` task. https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/5066

Comment: @jessehouwing dotnet test expects project/solution file in the root folder. What I am getting as root folder is artifact folder 'drop' which has deployable files not the actual proj/soln file

Answer (score 2):

We are running tests in **release** pipeline. 
Reason for that is, we want to do System tests - with newly released code.

In your pipeline tests are before - so it would be better to have them in **build** pipeline.

The way we are running .NET Core tests in release is made in two steps:

1. Publish folder with test project into artifacts
2. In release pipeline add two .NET Core steps

   - Command: restore, Path: path to your *test.csproj*
   - Command: test, Path: path to your *test.csproj*, Arguments: --no-build -c Release